# How to exclude symbols from dll build with MinGW-w64?

Tags: dll, linker, mingw, ld, mingw-w64

I built a custom dll that relies on a 3d party static library with Ming-w64. My problem is that the dll exports all the 3d party static library symbols in addition to the functions I marked for export with **__declspec(dllexport)**.
I would like only the symbols of the functions I marked for export with **__declspec(dllexport)** to be exported.

I could not find specific documentation about ld for Ming-w64, but I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/win32.html) about ld for Cygwin / MinGW:

> Exporting DLL symbols.
>
> The cygwin/mingw ld has several ways to export symbols for dll's.
>
> > Using auto-export functionality:
> >
> > > By default ld exports symbols with the auto-export functionality, which is controlled by the following command line options:
> > >
> > > -export-all-symbols [This is the default]
> > >
> > > -exclude-symbols
> > >
> > > -exclude-libs
> > >
> > > If, however, -export-all-symbols is not given explicitly on the command line, then the default auto-export behavior will be disabled if either of the following are true:
> > >
> > > A DEF file is used.
> > >
> > > Any symbol in any object file was marked with the __declspec(dllexport) attribute.

From the above, ld for MinGW and ld for MinGW-w64 seem to behave differently. I was expecting the 3d party static library symbols to not be exported since there are symbols marked with **__declspec(dllexport)** in the object file. I also tried to use **-exclude-libs=ALL** to resolve the issue but it didn’t seem to have any effect.

Is the behavior I’m experiencing with  MinGW-w64 normal?

If yes, how could I achieve my goal?

Comment: What's the library?

Comment: The 3d party static library is Lua (5.2.4).